# SASI indexes on year and month

Tags: cassandra

I am new to SASI indexes in Cassandra and I am unclear how they index when multiple columns are included in the "where" predicate that are indexed.

Here is one option I am looking at:

Option 1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_timeseries_data (
  id text, 
  event_time timestamp,
  value text,
  year int,
  month int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, event_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time DESC);

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX year_idx ON my_timeseries_data  (year) 
USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
WITH OPTIONS = { 'mode': 'SPARSE' };

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX month_idx ON my_timeseries_data  (month) 
USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
WITH OPTIONS = { 'mode': 'SPARSE' };
```

I expect to query like this sometimes:

```
select * from my_timeseries_data
where year = 2016 and month = 1  ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Does the SASI index on 'month' column help my performance?

Option 2:

Would it be better to index a concatenated column like 'year_and_month' below?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_timeseries_data (
      id text, 
      event_time timestamp,
      value text,
      year_and_month text,
      PRIMARY KEY (id, event_time)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time DESC);

    CREATE CUSTOM INDEX year_idx ON my_timeseries_data  (year_and_month) 
    USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
```

And then query like this on a single SASI index:

```
select * from my_timeseries_data
where year_and_month = '2016_1';
```

Option 3:

NO need for extra month and year columns and SASI indexes because having 'event_time' as a CLUSTERING COLUMN allows scalable time-range queries that I want to do anway?